# Create a new obj with deepcopy but new obj share variable with the old obj

Tags: python, copy, shared-memory, deep-copy, class-variables

I am dealing with some classes using pygraph module and when I use add_node() method, it always comes out 'node xxx already in graph'. So I try to use deepcopy() to create a new instance and have some problem with it:

```
class test:
   _storage = []
   def add_item(self,item):
       self._storage.append(item)

   def pop_item(self,item):
       return self._storage.pop()

   def __repr__(self):
       return '%s' %self._storage[:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
   a1 = test()
   a1.add_item(3)
   a1.add_item(4)
   from copy import copy,deepcopy
   a2 = copy(a1)
   a3 = deepcopy(a2)
```

it shows:

```
In[28]: a1
Out[28]: [3, 4]

In[29]: a2
Out[29]: [3, 4]

In[30]: a3
Out[30]: [3, 4]
```

but if I add some new item into the list a2, a3 changes too

```
In[31]: a1.add_item(440)

In[32]: a2
Out[32]: [3, 4, 440]

In[33]: a3
Out[33]: [3, 4, 440]
```

So how can I just copy some instance and the variables of it are independent from variables in the old instance ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_storage` is a class variable. `deepcopy` won't make a new copy of the whole class, so copies will still share the same class variables. What you want is an instance variable:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._storage = []
```

Comment: Thanks, but a2,a3 still changes with a1,so they still share the _storage and I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: @user3001921: That shouldn't be happening. The `deepcopy`d object should have its own `_storage`. Show us the new version of your code. Did you spell `__init__` right? Did you remove the class-level `_storage`? Did you make `__init__` a method of `test`?

Comment: this is the correct answer  .... as demonstrated in my answer ... there are other ways to do it but this is the clear way to do it in your instance

Comment: @user2357112:it really works,a2 = copy(a1)will change with a1,while a3 = deepcopy(a1)won't, thanks for your help. if I define a variable in the class but not in any method,does it mean I define a class-level variable and this variable will share in all instances?

Comment: thanks @JoranBeasley,amazing usage but it will be a hard time if the class is complex

Answer (score 1):

```
class test:
   storage = []
   def add_item(self,item):
       self.storage.append(item)       
   def pop_item(self,item):
       return self.storage.pop()      
   def __repr__(self):
       return '%s' %self.storage[:]
   def __copy__(self):
        print "COPY!!!" #define explicit copy behaviour
        s = self.__class__()
        s.storage = self.storage[:] # make a copy of the list rather than a pointer to same
        return s

 from copy import copy
 a = test()
 a.add_item(3)
 a.add_item(4)
 b = copy(a) #this will call the __copy__ method of the class
 b.add_item(244)
 a.add_item(5)
 print a,b
```

alternatively you could just create a `copy` method on the class and call `b = a.copy()`

or you can use the solution from user2357112 which does indeed work (and is much more pythonic if you donot actually need to define explicit behaviour)

```
>>> class test:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.storage = []
...    def add_item(self,item):
...        self.storage.append(item)
...    def pop_item(self,item):
...        return self.storage.pop()
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return '%s' %self.storage[:]
...
>>> a = test()
>>> a.add_item(1)
>>> b = deepcopy(a)
>>> b.add_item(4)
>>> b
[1, 4]
>>> a
[1]
```