# Create independent Object in Python using deepCopy

Tags: python, deep-copy

Issue is that I am unable to create an independent copy of megaNode into newMegaNode using deepcopy(). It seems even after using it, the newMeganode and megaNode are binded together. Am I doing anything wrong in this? In the output everything gets binded to megaNoda even though I had specifically used deepcopy() to copy its content into newMegaNode and added to newList.

```
   def newAlgo():
        global nodeQueue
        initalNode = AnswersAlgo();
        scratchList = []
        scratchList.append(initalNode)

        newList = []
        for node in nodeQueue:

            for megaNode in scratchList:
                if validation(node,megaNode):
                    newMegaNode = copy.deepcopy(megaNode) #Unable to create independent object
                    newList.append([node,newMegaNode])


        for x,y in newList:     
            scratchList.append(y.addToList(x))
```

Comment: I have no idea what `AnswersAlgo` is, but there can be issues using `deepcopy` on objects of user classes.  This is because constructors (`__init__`) often have other side effects, for example setting or updating class variables, so creating a new object without calling a constructor can be dangerous.  The class can implement a `__deepcopy__` to avoid this, but few do.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in python 2.x if you don't inherit from "object" in class definition, the class behavior gets confusing.  If you're python version is 2.x make sure you class inherits from "object" like this:

```
class megaNode(object):
    ...
```

Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177109/create-a-new-obj-with-deepcopy-but-new-obj-share-variable-with-the-old-obj?rq=1)